# When I try to make a dictionary within a class, it overrides the dictionaries in all other instances of said class.

Tags: python, dictionary

When I try to add an entry to a dictionary within a class, it overrides dictionaries in all other instances of that class. Is there a way to make the dictionaries unique to each instance of the class?

```
class Object:
    dictionary = {}

    def __init__(self):
        return


a = Object()
a.dictionary["abc"] = "Hello, World!"

b = Object()
b.dictionary["abc"] = "Goodbye, World!"

print(a.dictionary["abc"])
```

In this example, it prints `"Goodbye, World!"`. I would think `a.dictionary` and `b.dictionary` are two separate entities, so changing one should have no effect on the other. Is there a way I can have unique dictionaries for `a` and `b` so that I can manipulate one without affecting the other, so `a.dictionary["abc"]` is `"Hello, World!"` and `b.dictionary["abc"]` is `"Goodbye, World!"`?

Comment: You need to use an instance variable, not a class variable (i.e. a "static" variable)

Comment: use `def __init__(self): self.dictionary = {}`

Answer (score 0):

You have to define `dictionary` inside `__init__(self)`.

```
class Object:

    def __init__(self):
        self.dictionary = {}

a = Object()
a.dictionary['abc'] = 'Hello, World!'


b = Object()
b.dictionary['abc'] = 'Goodbye World!'

print(a.dictionary['abc'])
```

If you define `dictionary` outside `__init__(self)`, it will be common for all instances of `Object` (kind of like `static` variables in Java).

If you define it inside `__init__(self)`, then it would be attributed to only a particular instance of an object, this is because, `self` would refer to that particular object in that case.